# add custom tags to DOMDocument with php

Tags: php, domdocument

Maybe i am googling for the wrong keywords but is there not a way to add a custom tag so that DOMDocument can find custom tags. When i my html file i get lots of errors and of course getElementsByTagName returns nothing.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile('my html file');
$dom->getElementsByTagName('un_welcome_text');
```

Does not fail.
I realize this is not the best practice, but this code i have to parse is legacy stuff that can not change.

the html looks like, an i have to get everything between

```
 <body>
   <u_top></u_top>
      <u_welcome_text>
       A BUNCH OF HTML
      </u_welcome_text>        
 </body>
```

Comment: 10 years later, I'm having the same problem. :) Did you find a solution?